# program that determines day number tips

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a c program that determines the day number (1 to 366) in a year for a date provided by a user.
How do I adjust this program for a leap year like (december 31,2012) is day 366 since it was a leap year. This is my code so far. Im thinking I need an if staement before switch but I dont know how to implement please help

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isleap(int year);

void  displaydate(int month ,int date ,int year,int daynumber);

int main (void) {

    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    int leapyear;
    int daynumber;

    printf(" enter a month");
    scanf("%d",&month);

    printf(" enter a day");
    scanf("%d",&day);

    printf(" enter a year");
    scanf("%d",&year);

    leapyear= isleap( year);

    displaydate( month,day,year,daynumber);

    daynumber = leapyear && month > 2 ? day+1 : day;

    switch(month) {

        case 1 : daynumber = day;
                break;

        case 2 : daynumber = 31 + day;
                break;

        case 3 : daynumber = 59 + day + 1; 
                break;

        case 4 : daynumber = 89 + day;
                break;  

        case 5 : daynumber = 120 + day;
                break;  

        case 6 : daynumber = 150 + day;
                break; 

        case 7 : daynumber = 181 + day;
                break;  

        case 8 : daynumber = 212 + day;
                break;   

        case 9 : daynumber = 232 + day;
                break;  

        case 10 : daynumber = 263 + day;
                break;  

        case 11 : daynumber = 293 + day;
                break;  

        case 12 : daynumber = 324 + day;
                break;

        default:
                break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int isleap(int year)
{
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100!= 0)) || (year%400 == 0)) {
        printf("%d  1", year);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d 0", year);
        return 0; 
    }
}

void  displaydate(int month ,int date ,int year,int daynumber)
{ 
    printf("\n your date is %d and the day number is %d",month,date,year,daynumber);

}
```

Comment: If it's a leap year and month is more than 2, add 1.

Comment: when i try to run the code it says day number is not declared in the scope

Comment: Why are you calling `displaydate()` before the `switch()` statement that calculates the day number?

Comment: You should be adding 1 in `main()`, after the `switch` statement, not in `isleap()`.

Comment: `isleap()` shouldn't print something, it's supposed to return `0` or `1` depending on whether it's a leap year.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn you that the function is missing a `return` statement?

Comment: Why do you have an extra `+ 1` in `case 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other issues raised, your math is wrong on the number of days to add in your `switch` statement. It should be:

```
    switch (month) {
        case 1 :  daynumber = day; break;
        case 2 :  daynumber = 31  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 3 :  daynumber = 59  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 4 :  daynumber = 90  + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 5 :  daynumber = 120 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 6 :  daynumber = 151 + day + leapyear; break; 
        case 7 :  daynumber = 181 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 8 :  daynumber = 212 + day + leapyear; break;   
        case 9 :  daynumber = 243 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 10 : daynumber = 273 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 11 : daynumber = 304 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 12 : daynumber = 334 + day + leapyear; break;
        default: break;
    }
```

You also cannot display the `daynumber` before it is computed, you need to order you computations as follows:

```
    ...
    leapyear = isleap (year);

    switch (month) {
        case 1 :  daynumber = day; break;
        case 2 :  daynumber = 31  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 3 :  daynumber = 59  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 4 :  daynumber = 90  + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 5 :  daynumber = 120 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 6 :  daynumber = 151 + day + leapyear; break; 
        case 7 :  daynumber = 181 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 8 :  daynumber = 212 + day + leapyear; break;   
        case 9 :  daynumber = 243 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 10 : daynumber = 273 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 11 : daynumber = 304 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 12 : daynumber = 334 + day + leapyear; break;
        default: break;
    }

    displaydate (month, day, year, daynumber);
    ...
```

Your `printf` statement in `displaydate` fails to provide *conversion specifiers* for each of the parameters you pass. It appears you intended:

```
void displaydate (int month, int date, int year, int daynumber)
{ 
    printf ("\n your date is %d/%d/%d and the day number is %d\n",
            month, date, year, daynumber);
}
```

**note:** the `"%d/%d/%d"` for `mm/dd/yyyy`

If you put all those pieces together, you would get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isleap (int year);

void displaydate (int month, int date , int year, int daynumber);

int main (void) {

    int month = 0,
        day = 0,
        year = 0,
        leapyear = 0,
        daynumber = 0;

    printf (" enter month: ");
    scanf ("%d", &month);

    printf (" enter day: ");
    scanf ("%d", &day);

    printf (" enter year: ");
    scanf ("%d", &year);

    leapyear = isleap (year);

    switch (month) {
        case 1 :  daynumber = day; break;
        case 2 :  daynumber = 31  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 3 :  daynumber = 59  + day + leapyear; break;
        case 4 :  daynumber = 90  + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 5 :  daynumber = 120 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 6 :  daynumber = 151 + day + leapyear; break; 
        case 7 :  daynumber = 181 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 8 :  daynumber = 212 + day + leapyear; break;   
        case 9 :  daynumber = 243 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 10 : daynumber = 273 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 11 : daynumber = 304 + day + leapyear; break;  
        case 12 : daynumber = 334 + day + leapyear; break;
        default: break;
    }

    displaydate (month, day, year, daynumber);

    return 0;
}

int isleap (int year)
{
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
        return 1;

    return 0; 
}

void displaydate (int month, int date, int year, int daynumber)
{ 
    printf ("\n your date is %d/%d/%d and the day number is %d\n",
            month, date, year, daynumber);
}
```

Further, note, you must validate ALL user input (omitted above). At minimum you should check the return on each `scanf` similar to:

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &month) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid month entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator, just add this code before you switch:

```
day = leapyear && month > 2 ? day+1 : day;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int isleap(int year)
{
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100!= 0)) || (year%400 == 0))
        printf("%d  1", year);
    else
        printf("%d 0", year);

}
```

Above function should return whether it is leap year or not, so change the code to return properly as below.

```
int isleap(int year)
{
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100!= 0)) || (year%400 == 0)){
        printf("%d  1", year);
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("%d 0", year);
        return 0; }

}
```

Now add below statement above switch case to increment a day if it is a leap year and month is greater than 2.

```
day = leapyear  && (month>2) ? day+1 : day;
```

Now you will get the result properly.

Hope this will help.

Comment: im getting an error on line 97 saying function definition not allowed here.